# h2o - deep learning Cartesian grid search - same train& validation - same hyper parameters generate different model

Tags: h2o

I am a newbee in AI/ML and found h2o recently.

I am experimenting with grid search for deep learning using Cartesian search since I want to run all different combinations. I had two runs using the same train and validation files and same set of hyper search parameters along with the grid.train parameters. Both runs generate same number of models and each model is generated with same input parameters "activation  adaptive_rate  epsilon  hidden  hidden_dropout_ratios  input_dropout_ratio  rho".

My observation is that for each run using same input parameters, the model generated has a different logloss, mean per class error, MSE, RMSE, etc.
To reduce further user errors, I just limited the grid search to only 1 set of parameters. My finding are below with detailed logs, etc.

My question is how do I guarantee that the model generated are exactly the same, given the same set of parameters and train/validation frame.

*Train & Validation file format and data*

```
BPS1,BPS2,ZSRTN,PCNT_RTN,PCNT_RTN100,Open,High,Low,Close,Time
58,18  ,  3.00  , -0.12  , -12  , 297.2700  , 297.3100  , 297.0800  , 297.1700  , 201907050935
18,20  ,  3.00  , -0.11  , -11  , 297.1800  , 297.1900  , 296.9300  , 296.9400  , 201907050940
20,20  ,  5.00  ,  0.01  , 1  , 296.9400  , 297.2600  , 296.8200  , 297.2150  , 201907050945
20,30  ,  5.00  ,  0.03  , 3  , 297.2200  , 297.2600  , 297.0400  , 297.0400  , 201907050950
```

*Values*

```
activation = RectifierWithDropout
adaptive_rate = true
epsilon = 1.0E-6
hidden = [200]
hidden_dropout_ratios = [0.1]
input_dropout_ratio 0.05
rho = 0.9
```

*Python Code*

```
    hyper_parameters = {
            "hidden": [[200]],
            "epsilon" : 1.0E-6,
            "adaptive_rate": True,
            "activation": ["RectifierWithDropout"],
            "input_dropout_ratio" : [0.05],
            "hidden_dropout_ratios" : [0.1],
            "rho":[0.9]
            }



.....

    search_criteria = {"strategy": "Cartesian"}

.....

    model_grid = H2OGridSearch(model = H2ODeepLearningEstimator,
        grid_id = project_name,
        hyper_params=hyper_parameters,
        search_criteria=search_criteria)



    model_grid.train(x=x,
        y = response_column,
        distribution=default_distribution, epochs=10000,
        training_frame=train, validation_frame=test,
        score_interval=0, stopping_rounds=5,
        stopping_tolerance=1e-3,
        stopping_metric="mean_per_class_error")
```

*Prepare for First run*

```
07-02 09:27:45.989 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  #75857-26 INFO: Starting gridsearch: estimated size of search space = 1
07-02 09:27:45.990 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-51   INFO: Due to the grid time limit, changing model max runtime to: 1.7976931348623157E308 secs.
07-02 09:27:45.992 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-51   INFO: Building H2O DeepLearning model with these parameters:
07-02 09:27:45.992 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-51   INFO: {"_train":{"name":"py_1_sid_b81b","type":"Key"},"_valid":{"name":"py_2_sid_b81b","type":"Key"},"_nfolds":0,"_keep_cross_validation_models":true,"_keep_cross_validation_predictions":false,"_keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment":false,"_parallelize_cross_validation":true,"_auto_rebalance":true,"_seed":-1,"_fold_assignment":"AUTO","_categorical_encoding":"AUTO","_max_categorical_levels":10,"_distribution":"AUTO","_tweedie_power":1.5,"_quantile_alpha":0.5,"_huber_alpha":0.9,"_ignored_columns":["Close","PCNT_RTN100","High","Low","PCNT_RTN","Time","Open"],"_ignore_const_cols":true,"_weights_column":null,"_offset_column":null,"_fold_column":null,"_check_constant_response":true,"_is_cv_model":false,"_score_each_iteration":false,"_max_runtime_secs":1.7976931348623157E308,"_stopping_rounds":5,"_stopping_metric":"mean_per_class_error","_stopping_tolerance":0.001,"_response_column":"ZSRTN","_balance_classes":false,"_max_after_balance_size":5.0,"_class_sampling_factors":null,"_max_confusion_matrix_size":20,"_checkpoint":null,"_pretrained_autoencoder":null,"_custom_metric_func":null,"_custom_distribution_func":null,"_export_checkpoints_dir":null,"_overwrite_with_best_model":true,"_autoencoder":false,"_use_all_factor_levels":true,"_standardize":true,"_activation":"RectifierWithDropout","_hidden":[200],"_epochs":10000.0,"_train_samples_per_iteration":-2,"_target_ratio_comm_to_comp":0.05,"_adaptive_rate":true,"_rho":0.9,"_epsilon":1.0E-6,"_rate":0.005,"_rate_annealing":1.0E-6,"_rate_decay":1.0,"_momentum_start":0.0,"_momentum_ramp":1000000.0,"_momentum_stable":0.0,"_nesterov_accelerated_gradient":true,"_input_dropout_ratio":0.05,"_hidden_dropout_ratios":[0.1],"_l1":0.0,"_l2":0.0,"_max_w2":3.4028235E38,"_initial_weight_distribution":"UniformAdaptive","_initial_weight_scale":1.0,"_initial_weights":null,"_initial_biases":null,"_loss":"Automatic","_score_interval":0.0,"_score_training_samples":10000,"_score_validation_samples":0,"_score_duty_cycle":0.1,"_classification_stop":0.0,"_regression_stop":1.0E-6,"_quiet_mode":false,"_score_validation_sampling":"Uniform","_diagnostics":true,"_variable_importances":true,"_fast_mode":true,"_force_load_balance":true,"_replicate_training_data":true,"_single_node_mode":false,"_shuffle_training_data":false,"_missing_values_handling":"MeanImputation","_sparse":false,"_col_major":false,"_average_activation":0.0,"_sparsity_beta":0.0,"_max_categorical_features":2147483647,"_reproducible":false,"_export_weights_and_biases":false,"_elastic_averaging":false,"_elastic_averaging_moving_rate":0.9,"_elastic_averaging_regularization":0.001,"_mini_batch_size":1}
07-02 09:27:45.992 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-51   INFO: Dropping ignored columns: [Close, PCNT_RTN100, High, Low, PCNT_RTN, Time, Open]
07-02 09:27:45.992 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-51   INFO: Dataset already contains 128 chunks. No need to rebalance.
07-02 09:27:45.993 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-51   INFO: Starting model DeepLearning__gen_202007020927_m_5_r_2_b_2_pp_0.05_l_1_t_10_model_1
```

*Result of 1st run*

```
07-02 09:27:51.513 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  #75857-30 INFO: Hyper-Parameter Search Summary (ordered by increasing logloss):
07-02 09:27:51.513 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  #75857-30 INFO:             activation  adaptive_rate  epsilon  hidden  hidden_dropout_ratios  input_dropout_ratio  rho                                                            model_ids             logloss
07-02 09:27:51.513 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  #75857-30 INFO:   RectifierWithDropout           true   1.0E-6   [200]                  [0.1]                 0.05  0.9  DeepLearning__gen_202007020927_m_5_r_2_b_2_pp_0.05_l_1_t_10_model_1  1.7762588168309075
```

*Prepare for Second run*

```
07-02 09:32:49.293 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  #75857-29 INFO: Starting gridsearch: estimated size of search space = 1
07-02 09:32:49.293 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-25   INFO: Due to the grid time limit, changing model max runtime to: 1.7976931348623157E308 secs.
07-02 09:32:49.294 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-25   INFO: Building H2O DeepLearning model with these parameters:
07-02 09:32:49.294 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-25   INFO: {"_train":{"name":"py_1_sid_aeed","type":"Key"},"_valid":{"name":"py_2_sid_aeed","type":"Key"},"_nfolds":0,"_keep_cross_validation_models":true,"_keep_cross_validation_predictions":false,"_keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment":false,"_parallelize_cross_validation":true,"_auto_rebalance":true,"_seed":-1,"_fold_assignment":"AUTO","_categorical_encoding":"AUTO","_max_categorical_levels":10,"_distribution":"AUTO","_tweedie_power":1.5,"_quantile_alpha":0.5,"_huber_alpha":0.9,"_ignored_columns":["Time","Open","PCNT_RTN","PCNT_RTN100","Low","Close","High"],"_ignore_const_cols":true,"_weights_column":null,"_offset_column":null,"_fold_column":null,"_check_constant_response":true,"_is_cv_model":false,"_score_each_iteration":false,"_max_runtime_secs":1.7976931348623157E308,"_stopping_rounds":5,"_stopping_metric":"mean_per_class_error","_stopping_tolerance":0.001,"_response_column":"ZSRTN","_balance_classes":false,"_max_after_balance_size":5.0,"_class_sampling_factors":null,"_max_confusion_matrix_size":20,"_checkpoint":null,"_pretrained_autoencoder":null,"_custom_metric_func":null,"_custom_distribution_func":null,"_export_checkpoints_dir":null,"_overwrite_with_best_model":true,"_autoencoder":false,"_use_all_factor_levels":true,"_standardize":true,"_activation":"RectifierWithDropout","_hidden":[200],"_epochs":10000.0,"_train_samples_per_iteration":-2,"_target_ratio_comm_to_comp":0.05,"_adaptive_rate":true,"_rho":0.9,"_epsilon":1.0E-6,"_rate":0.005,"_rate_annealing":1.0E-6,"_rate_decay":1.0,"_momentum_start":0.0,"_momentum_ramp":1000000.0,"_momentum_stable":0.0,"_nesterov_accelerated_gradient":true,"_input_dropout_ratio":0.05,"_hidden_dropout_ratios":[0.1],"_l1":0.0,"_l2":0.0,"_max_w2":3.4028235E38,"_initial_weight_distribution":"UniformAdaptive","_initial_weight_scale":1.0,"_initial_weights":null,"_initial_biases":null,"_loss":"Automatic","_score_interval":0.0,"_score_training_samples":10000,"_score_validation_samples":0,"_score_duty_cycle":0.1,"_classification_stop":0.0,"_regression_stop":1.0E-6,"_quiet_mode":false,"_score_validation_sampling":"Uniform","_diagnostics":true,"_variable_importances":true,"_fast_mode":true,"_force_load_balance":true,"_replicate_training_data":true,"_single_node_mode":false,"_shuffle_training_data":false,"_missing_values_handling":"MeanImputation","_sparse":false,"_col_major":false,"_average_activation":0.0,"_sparsity_beta":0.0,"_max_categorical_features":2147483647,"_reproducible":false,"_export_weights_and_biases":false,"_elastic_averaging":false,"_elastic_averaging_moving_rate":0.9,"_elastic_averaging_regularization":0.001,"_mini_batch_size":1}
07-02 09:32:49.295 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-25   INFO: Dropping ignored columns: [Time, Open, PCNT_RTN, PCNT_RTN100, Low, Close, High]
07-02 09:32:49.295 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-25   INFO: Dataset already contains 128 chunks. No need to rebalance.
07-02 09:32:49.295 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  FJ-1-25   INFO: Starting model DeepLearning__gen_202007020932_m_5_r_2_b_2_pp_0.05_l_1_t_10_model_1
```

*Results of second run*

```
07-02 09:32:53.914 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  #75857-32 INFO: Hyper-Parameter Search Summary (ordered by increasing logloss):
07-02 09:32:53.914 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  #75857-32 INFO:             activation  adaptive_rate  epsilon  hidden  hidden_dropout_ratios  input_dropout_ratio  rho                                                            model_ids             logloss
07-02 09:32:53.914 192.168.123.5:54321   #7248  #75857-32 INFO:   RectifierWithDropout           true   1.0E-6   [200]                  [0.1]                 0.05  0.9  DeepLearning__gen_202007020932_m_5_r_2_b_2_pp_0.05_l_1_t_10_model_1  1.7002255980952898
```